# Jquery will not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple jquery will not load

```
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#p1").on("click", function(){
            $("#p1").slideUp(300);
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you could please help, because I cannot work with jQuery!

Comment: For a complete, reproducible example, you also need the relevant html.

Comment: @ps2goat Simple quick thing. I thought needed HTML, but this is syntax error.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it may be true that you offered a working fix for the OP, but other people having a similar problem will try your answer and they still may have questions because there is no html for the jquery to operate on.

Comment: @ps2goat Agreed... Added some more code.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you give separate `<script>` tags. You cannot have `src` as well as content with the same tag. Have two tags for each `src` and the content like below:

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#p1").on("click", function(){
            $("#p1").slideUp(300);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, another best practise is, if both the target and source are same, you can make use of `this`:

```
$("#p1").on("click", function(){
    $(this).slideUp(300);
});
```